# Difference between bases and topology

Tags: general-topology

Be $X$ a set and $B$ a collection of subsets of $X$ satisfying the following properties:
(1) For each $U_1$, $U_2$ and each $x\in U_1\cap U_2$, there is $U\in B$ such that $x \in U\subseteq U_1\cap U_2$.
(2) For each $x\in X$, there is $U\in B$ such as $x\in U$.

So the $B^{\ast}$, formed by the $B$ subcollection unions, is a topology about $X$ and $B$ is a basis for the $(X,B^{\ast})$topological space.

Let $X$ be a non-empty, fixed set $x_{0} \in X$ arbitrary. Show that $B = \{\{x\}: x \in X\backslash\{x_0\}\} \cup \{X\}$ is a base for a topology over $X$.

How can I prove that given $U_1$ and $U_2$ and a point at the intersection then there is $U$ at the intersection, such as $x$ is at $U$ ?
Also, how can I show (2), which always exists $x\in X$, is there $U\in B$ such that $x\in U$?

Answer (score 3):

1. If $U_1=U_2=X$ then choose $U=X$, otherwise, assume e.g. $U_1=\{y\}$ and $x\in U_1\cap U_2$ then $x=y$ and $U=U_1$ will work.
2. We have $X\in B$.

Comment: @Brian But shouldn't we prove the general case? Given $U_1$ and $U_2$ it. I didn't understand why $U_1=U_2=X$. Could explain?

Comment: It's not explicitly written but $U_1,U_2\in B$: (1) For every $U_1,U_2\in B$ and each $x\in U_1\cap U_2$ there's an $U\in B: x\in U\subseteq U_1\cap U_2$.